# How i can deal with a request that depend of other request without using subscribe inside subscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Nowadays i have one function that makes a http request, when i have the response i do other http request that depends of the success result of the first request.

I have this structure:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.service.get().subscribe((res) => {
      this.service2.get().subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      }, (err) => {
        this.toastr.error(err.statusText);
      })
    }, (err) => {
      this.toastr.error(err.statusText);
    });
  }
```

I think this is hard to understand and i'm trying to make it in a more appropriete way.

There's a way to extract this in two functions, each with yours errors and concat with some Rxjs operator?

Comment: Have a look at `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `switchMap` operators.

Comment: Depends on your use case but there's mutliple way to do this via `concatMap()` `mergeMap()` `forkJoin()` etc, but seems like you'll want `forkJoin` from the look of your code you want all observable to complete.

Comment: @penleychan I need to call the second service only if the first http request don't throw an error. With forkJoin the both of request will be calling in the same time, right?

Comment: @veroneseComS, then switchMap will just do fine for you.

Comment: you may find [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a) interesting for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of the `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `switchMap` operators. Which one exactly, depends on how many results your first observable will emit, and how you want to handle the situations where the first observable emits again before the 2nd one finished.

```js
onSubmit() {
  this.service.get()
    .pipe(
      .switchMap(result1 => {
        // this will be called once the first call finished, with it's result
        // here you can use the first result
        console.log(`result of the service1 call: ${result1}`);
        // you could even pass it to the 2nd one if it needed it
        // here you have to return an observable
        return this.service2.get();
      }),
      .catchError(err => {
        // you can omit this `catchError`
        // here you can handle errors, but this will receive errors from either of the service calls
        // and you have to return an observable from here too
      })
    ).subscribe(result2 => console.log(`result of service2 call: ${result2}`))
}
```

Comment: i will test it and return later

Comment: i've been testing the switchMap but i think this still is not what i want because if the first request throws an error, the second still wil be executed, i think the concatMap works like i expect.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as your answer so we can close the question. Thanks!

Comment: @veroneseComS no, if the first request throws an error, the 2nd one will not be executed. That would only be the case, if the catchError was before the switchMap, but that is not a difference between these mapping operators.